# How to create a trigger that checks a field from the object is fired from

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-field, unique-field

Hello and thanks in advanced.

-Background-

I have a custom object for files, one of the files recorded in this object needs to be the primary file, but only one.

-Approach-

Create a trigger that checks before the new insert if there is another record already mark as primary, if so show a warning, otherwise insert the record.

-Problem-

I'm new to Apex code, to triggers and everything. So, not sure why this is not working. When I'm creating a new record and check the primary file checkbox it doesn't creates the record. So I'm unable to see if the trigger worked.

-Code-

```
trigger trg_Custom_Object on Custom_Object__c (before insert) {

    Set <Id> filesId = new Set <Id>();

    List <Custom_Object__c> filesToSave = new List <Custom_Object__c>();

    for (Custom_Object__c files : Trigger.new) {
        //Check if trigger.new Primary_file__c is TRUE
        if (files.Primary_file__c){
            //Add the Id to a list of ids
            filesId.add(files.Id);
            filesToSave.add(files);
        }

    }
    //Query the ids from object where Primary_file__c is TRUE and is old
    List <Custom_Object__c> filesList = new List <Custom_Object__c> ([select id from Custom_Object__c where Primary_file__c = true and id not in :filesID] );

    for (Custom_Object__c files : Trigger.new) {
        //For each new record to be inserted check if its Primary_file__c is set to TRUE
        //and if there is already a file with Primary_file__c set TRUE
        if (files.Primary_file__c && filesList.size() > 0){
            //Trhows error
            files.Id.AddError('You cannot have more than one primary file');
        } else {
            //Insert new record
            //insert filesToSave; (Commented by @dschach because unnecessary.)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have another use case on update and delete. What happens if the primary file is deleted or someone tries to update a file to primary. You probably should cover this logic in your trigger as well.

Comment: That's correct, in the update case the idea will be to uncheck the previous file and mark the new. In the delete case doesn't matter, It's not necessary to have a record mark as primary always.

Comment: Could you clarify what isn't working about this more, which would assist with troubleshooting. Is it throwing an error?

Comment: Sure, just updated. (Update: When I'm creating a new record and check the primary file checkbox it doesn't creates the record. So I'm unable to see if the trigger worked.)

Comment: I think that your shoudn't call `insert`within an insert trigger of the same object. BTW: avoid insert in a loop

Comment: One of the problems that I can see is that you are trying to use the Id of the new record in a Before Insert trigger. At this point in the execution, Salesforce has not generated an Id for the record.

Comment: I see, thanks for that information. I also tried in an after insert and is still not working. @MarkMasterson

Comment: I would put some debug statements into the code - particularly: system.debug(files.Primary_file__c), and system.debug(files.filesList) to see what is happening with your conditional. Then perform an operation with the Developer Console open, or setup your profile to monitor debug logs. Also, as others have mentioned, the insert statement is necessary, you only need to check the condition and throw the error. The system will perform the insert on those records that do not meet the criteria for you.

Comment: I can't edit my last comment anymore, but just want to point out the serious typo: necessary should be unecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'll be answering my own question thanks to the comments above I was able to complete it.

-Here is the code.-

```
trigger trg_Custom_Object on Custom_Object__c (before insert, before update) {

    Set <Id> filesId = new Set <Id> ();
    set <Id> objectsID = new Set <Id> ();

   for (Custom_Object__c files : Trigger.new) {
       //Check if trigger.new Primary_file__c is TRUE
       System.debug('files.Primary_file__c: '+files.Primary_file__c);
       if (files.Primary_file__c){
           //Add the Id to a list of ids
           filesId.add(files.Id);
           objectsID.add(files.Object__c);
       }     
   }
    System.debug('Object: ' + objectsID);
    //Query the ids from object where Primary_file__c is TRUE and is not new
    List <Custom_Object__c> filesList = new List <Custom_Object__c> (
        [select id, Primary_file__c from Custom_Object__c where Primary_file__c = true and     id not in :filesID and Object__c in :objectsID] );
    //System.debug('filesList: '+ filesList);
    System.debug('filesList.size(): ' + filesList.size());

    for (Custom_Object__c files : Trigger.new) {
        if (filesList.size() > 0){
            files.Id.AddError(Label.Primary_file_already_created);
        } 
    }
}
```